# Multiple circles cut out from a div with CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I need to implement the following (minus the glyphicon on top) in html + css :

[image: A square with circles bitten off on each side]

For now, I'm stuck with

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(0px 45px, circle closest-corner, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 13px, gray 14px);
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/F7K4S/ ), which seems to be heading in a wrong direction, since I can't add a second semicircle.

Comment: Are the circles really cutout, i.e. do the things behind shine through, or are they just white? Is the Square always square and the same size? Do you mind using SVG as background?

Comment: Can they just be solid white semicircles, or do you need a real cutout?

Comment: Sometimes the easiest thing to do is use an image. This 'shape' would be better suited to an image or, better yet an inline SVG.

Comment: @Paulie_D you are probably right but I was wondering how we can measure (performance related) witch solution is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have already a good answer using pseudo elements.

If you want to keep your idea about using backgrounds with radial gradients, the answer would be this

```
.cutout {
    height: 88px;
    width: 88px;

    /* the inverse circle "cut" */
    background-image: 
        radial-gradient(circle at 44px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 13px, blue 14px),
        radial-gradient(circle at 0 24px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 13px, red 14px),
        radial-gradient(circle at 44px 24px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 13px, green 14px),
        radial-gradient(circle at 44px 20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 13px, blue 14px);
    background-size: 88px 20px, 44px 48px, 44px 48px, 88px 20px;
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 20px, 44px 20px, 0px 68px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7K4S/17/)

I have set different colors so that it is easy to see what is what.

Also, I have upgraded your notation to be w3c compliant, it is well supported in modern browsers.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a plain background color, you can use this CSS solution with pseudo elements and border-radius.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ELAdQ/)**

Output :

[image]

---

**EDIT 1 :**

As @Paulie_D mentioned, it is possible to make this shape responsive : **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ELAdQ/42/)**

---

**EDIT 2 :**

You could aslo use box-shadows in order to minimize markup (only one div and one pseudo element)

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ELAdQ/39/)**

---

Code for the first example :

*HTML :*

```
<div class="cutout"><div></div></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.cutout {
    height: 88px;
    width: 88px;
    position:relative;
    background:#808080;

}
.cutout:after, .cutout:before, .cutout >div:before, .cutout >div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:#fff;
}
.cutout:before{
    left:-15px;
    top:29px;
}
.cutout:after{
    left:29px;
    top:-15px;
}
.cutout >div:before{
    top:29px;
    right:-15px;
}
.cutout >div:after{
    bottom:-15px;
    left:29px;
}
```

Comment: Whenever I seem to come on here, you're constantly a half-step ahead of me :D .

Comment: @Samih that is because I've been hanging around here for a while now and I'm getting used to and like this type of question ;)

Comment: Building on original answers, this version is repsonsive to div size: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/ELAdQ/34/ O

Comment: Paulie, your responsive version works in Chrome, but breaks in Firefox and IE11.

Comment: @AndyM that is because you need to add the vendor prefixes http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ELAdQ/42/

Answer (score 3):

you have as well possibilitie to get those circle transparent if you draw background from pseudo shadows: http://jsfiddle.net/ELAdQ/40/

```
body {
    padding: 50px;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom left, gray, white, gray, white, gray, white, gray, white);
}
.cutout {
    height: 88px;
    width: 88px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.cutout:after, .cutout:before, .cutout >div:before, .cutout >div:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #808080
}
.cutout:before {
    left:-15px;
    top:29px;
}
.cutout:after {
    left:29px;
    top:-15px;
}
.cutout >div:before {
    top:29px;
    right:-15px;
}
.cutout >div:after {
    bottom:-15px;
    left:29px;
}
```

LIMITS: This works if pseudo shadows do not overlap other pseudo elements. Something bigger : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rikLp

Answer (score 2):

My circles are too big, but you get the idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/eZHx8/1/

Two extra containers:

```
<div  class="cutout">
    <div class="left-right"></div>
    <div class="top-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

And some CSS:

```
    body {
    padding: 50px;
}

.cutout {
    height: 88px;
    width: 88px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
}

.top-bottom:before, .top-bottom:after, .left-right:before, .left-right:after {
    content: '';
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

.top-bottom:before {

    top: -22px;
    left: 22px;
}

.top-bottom:after {
    bottom: -22px;
    left: 22px;
}

.left-right:before {
    top: 22px;
    left: -22px;
}

.left-right:after {
    bottom: 22px;
    right: -22px;
}
```